# how to display the information in php of two different table

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display the information in php of two different table with same data in it ony the name or id is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382808/how-to-display-the-information-in-php-of-two-different-table-with-same-data-in-i)

this code displays the both the information of the table
just want to display oly one table information which i select

as there are two tables menus and nonmenus.

and in those 2 tables n number of fields and items are given as input
so when i select one item of a table oly the information of those items are to be displayed

as it displays both the table information when i select a particular item of a table.

can any try n help..

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $_SESSION['n']=$_GET['id'];
}

$n=$_SESSION['n'];

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("menu",$con);
$sql="select * from menus where id=$n";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<table border=0 width=100%  ><tr>";
echo "<td><h1><img src=\"images/veg.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[tittle]</h1></td>"; ?> 
<?php echo" <td><h1><img src=\"images/telephone1.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[phone]    </h1></td>";
//<img src="images/Kapu-Lighthouse.jpg"  title="Non veg" width="210" height="150" />

//echo " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -<br>";
// echo "- $row[phone]"; 
echo "</tr></table>";
?> 
    <img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['photo'];?>" height=300 width= 550 alt="" />
    <?php
echo "<br> <a href=index.php>back</a>";


?>                    

   <?php
    echo"<h4>$row[address]</h4>";
   ?>          
<h1>Gallery</h1>

<table  border=7  cellspacing=10 > <tr>

<td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['gallery'];?>" height=150 width= 160 alt="" /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['gallery1'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['gallery2'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['gallery3'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['gallery4'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php mysql_close($con);   ?>
<!-- End veg items to be displayed in menu.php -->


 <!-- Non veg items to be displayed in menu.php -->
         <?php



                    if(isset($_GET['nid']))

{
    $_SESSION['n']=$_GET['nid'];
}

$n=$_SESSION['n'];


$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("menu",$con);
$sql="select * from nonmenu where id=$n";
echo "$sql";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<table border=0 width=100%  ><tr>";
echo "<td><h1><img src=\"images/non-veg.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[ntittle]</h1></td>"; ?> 
<?php echo" <td><h1><img src=\"images/telephone1.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[nphone]    </h1></td>";
//<img src="images/Kapu-Lighthouse.jpg"  title="Non veg" width="210" height="150" />

//echo " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -<br>";
// echo "- $row[phone]"; 
echo "</tr></table>";
?> 
    <img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['nphoto'];?>" height=300 width= 550 alt="" />
    <?php
echo "<br> <a href=index.php>back</a>";


?>                    

   <?php
    echo"<h4>$row[naddress]</h4>";
   ?>          
<h1>Gallery</h1>

<table  border=7  cellspacing=10 > <tr>

<td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['ngallery'];?>" height=150 width= 160 alt="" /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['ngallery1'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['ngallery2'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['ngallery3'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
  <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row['ngallery4'];?>"height=150 width= 160 /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php mysql_close($con); ?>
<!-- End Non veg items to be displayed in menu.php -->




        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: viral shah// can any one help how to check the feed back i am new to stack over flow  ..

Comment: Felipe Alameda A ur page is of no use....

Comment: Just refresh this page to check the feedback. It was not an answer to your question.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Make theme exclusive. This could work, if I understood right:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && (!isset($_GET['nid']))) {
// id tasks
die;
}

if(isset($_GET['nid']) && (!isset($_GET['id'])) ) { 
// nid tasks
die;
}
```

UPDATED:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) && ( !isset( $_GET[ 'nid' ] ) ) ) {
  $_SESSION[ 'n' ] = $_GET[ 'id' ];
  $n = $_SESSION[ 'n' ];
  $con = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" );
  mysql_select_db( "menu", $con );
  $sql    = "select * from menus where id=$n";
  $result = mysql_query( $sql );
  $row    = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
  echo "<table border=0 width=100%  ><tr>";
  echo "<td><h1><img src=\"images/veg.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[tittle]</h1></td>";
 ?>

<?php echo" <td><h1><img src=\"images/telephone1.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[phone]    </h1></td>";
  //<img src="images/Kapu-Lighthouse.jpg"  title="Non veg" width="210" height="150" />
  //echo " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -<br>";
  // echo "- $row[phone]";
  echo "</tr></table>";
  ?>
<img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'photo' ];?>" height=300 width=550 alt="" />
<?php
  echo "<br> <a href=index.php>back</a>";
  echo"<h4>$row[address]</h4>";
  ?>
<h1>Gallery</h1>
<table border=7 cellspacing=10>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'gallery' ];?>" height=150 width=160 alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'gallery1' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'gallery2' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'gallery3' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'gallery4' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php mysql_close( $con ); ?>
<!-- End veg items to be displayed in menu.php -->
<!-- Non veg items to be displayed in menu.php -->
<?php
}; die;
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'nid' ] ) && ( !isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ) ) {
  $_SESSION[ 'n' ] = $_GET[ 'nid' ];
  $n = $_SESSION[ 'n' ];
  $con = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" );
  mysql_select_db( "menu", $con );
  $sql = "select * from nonmenu where id=$n";
  echo "$sql";
  $result = mysql_query( $sql );
  $row    = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
  echo "<table border=0 width=100%  ><tr>";
  echo "<td><h1><img src=\"images/non-veg.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[ntittle]</h1></td>"; ?>
<?php echo" <td><h1><img src=\"images/telephone1.jpg\" height=35 width=35  /> $row[nphone]    </h1></td>";
  //<img src="images/Kapu-Lighthouse.jpg"  title="Non veg" width="210" height="150" />
  //echo " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -<br>";
  // echo "- $row[phone]";
  echo "</tr></table>";
  ?>
<img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'nphoto' ];?>" height=300 width=550 alt="" />
<?php
  echo "<br> <a href=index.php>back</a>";
  echo"<h4>$row[naddress]</h4>";
  ?>
<h1>Gallery</h1>
<table border=7 cellspacing=10>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'ngallery' ];?>" height=150 width=160 alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'ngallery1' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'ngallery2' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'ngallery3' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
    <td><img src="upload/<?php  echo $row[ 'ngallery4' ];?>" height=150 width=160 /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
  mysql_close( $con );
//End Non veg items to be displayed in menu.php
}; die;
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Felipe Alameda A : ur exactly right in the concept ..still it displays the both the results.. it take the same values of variable $n for both the displays..

Comment: OK. Add **die** as in the updated answer.

Comment: Felipe Alameda A: no it does not work.. its not able to differenciate which i clicked on when i click on a table 3rd id it even displays the information of b table same 3rd information of nid..

Comment: Try the updated answer. It should work. If it doesn't, sorry I could not help you.

Comment: Felipe Alameda A: no it even kills some of the css functions and displays oly one section of the table not other works

Comment: That's normal because the last </divs> where outside but that's something easy to correct, if it had worked. Sorry I could not be of any help. Hope someone else can, there are many great programmers in this site.

Comment: thank u lot lot  Felipe Alameda thank you